# How to query 5 year old data from ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I need to search all the documents which are older than 5 years from now. The documents contains a field called "capture_date". We can calculate how old they are from it.

```
{
    "_index" : "liberty-429-dev",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "7ed0f73d-a979-4497-b5cf-ab6854b0fd24",
    "_score" : null,
    "_source" : {
      "capture_date" : "2021-01-01",
      "vendor_invoice_number" : ""
    }
  },
  {
    "_index" : "liberty-429-dev",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "b442a1d5-bd37-4990-94ef-0a93c9e67450",
    "_score" : null,
    "_source" : {
      "capture_date" : "2021-01-02",
      "vendor_invoice_number" : "",
    }
}
```

These are some of the documents. Please suggest a get request query to search documents which are 5 years older than current date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [range query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html) to find the document that is 5 year older than the current date

```
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "capture_date": {
        "lt": "now-5y/y"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: it's not working. remember capture_date is in this format :- 2021-01-02

Comment: @MohamedAhkam  this will work for this date type format also. Can you please share some sample index data, on which you are testing this query ?

Comment: In above question i have shown the sample documents of the index. And i'm performing following query,

Comment: GET liberty-429-dev/_search
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "capture_date": {
        "lt": "now-5y/y"
      }
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
     "capture_date": "desc"
    }
  ]
}

Comment: @MohamedAhkam if you are using the same sample data as shown in the question, then you will get an empty result because there is no document that is older than 5 years (from the current date)

Comment: actually the capture_date varies from 1996 -2020. When i run above query i got only the documents with capture_date 1996. I tried by changing sort to  asc <-> desc as well. but everytime only the 1996 docs are shown.

Comment: @MohamedAhkam that means the query is working but you are not getting all the result. Elasticsearch by default returns only 10 documents. If you are having more than 10 documents then you need to set the `size` parameter

Comment: found the issue . Thanks for the help

Comment: btw, from here "now-5y/y" are we only considering the years? So if now =2020.05.12 and in 2015, from month 1-5 also be considered from above query?

Comment: Accepted again. Earlier I thought it was working with months and days well. But doesn't matter. Thanks for your help. And let me know if you can give a solution to the months and days well to find a proper time period